# A riddle from Candy Cadet

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, logic-grid

I am Candy Cadet, come get your candy here. I have candy all day, everyday. Candy. Candy. Candy.

Now I will tell you a story about a young woman who was sealed in a small room. In the room was a furnace and five keys. She was told that each of the five keys would unlock one of five doors outside her room. Inside each room was a child that she could take with her as she fled the building. But she was only allowed to leave her own room with one key, not all five. Desperate to find a way to save all five children, what did she do to the keys?

The answer's words must fill in the following format: Xxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx

Hint:

> Each word involves a key.

This is a puzzle based on a small story told by the character [Candy Cadet](https://freddy-fazbears-pizza.fandom.com/wiki/Candy_Cadet) from the indie horror game Freddy Fazbear's Pizza Simulator.

Comment: fused??? them in the furnace?

Comment: https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/all-of-candy-cadets-stories-in-freddy-fazbears-pizzeria-simulator/

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, that is the "official answer".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a parable than a puzzle.

Comment: If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, keep in mind that (at least here) puzzles are not interactive challenges—potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter (or whatever the setter is plugging offered answers into) as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's not a good fit here.

Answer (score 1):

She:

> Final answer: compound keys in the furnace. (obviously didn't work, and they all died.)

Comment: Although rot13(gurl nyy qvrq va gur fgbel)

Comment: it's incorrect is there another 8 letters word that fits the answer?

Comment: So the idea is correct but the word I'm using is not?

Comment: How about now...